# Determine if an interface has a custom attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, attributes, custom-attributes

I've got a custom attribute:

```
public class InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute : Attribute
{
    //...
}
```

The attribute is applied to an interface (**not on a property**).

```
namespace DAL.Model
{
    [InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute] //<--custom attribute
    public interface IActivity_part
    { 
        string ActivityName { get; set; }
        ActivityTypeEnum ActivityType { get; set; }
        bool IsActivityDetailsCompleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Using reflections I want to scan the assembly and check for all interfaces that have my custom attribute:

```
Assembly[] assemblyArray = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
var assTypes = assemblyArray[8].GetTypes(); //the 9th assembly is the one I've applied the attribute... this is irrelevant
string ns = "DAL.Model";
for (int i = 0; i < assTypes.Length; i++)
{
    bool hasDataContractAttribute = assTypes[i].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute), true).Any();

    if (assTypes[i].IsInterface && assTypes[i].Namespace == ns && hasDataContractAttribute == true)
    {
        if (assTypes[i].Name == "IActivity_part")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("type found!");
        }


        Console.WriteLine("zr type: " + assTypes[i].Name);
        Console.WriteLine("zr ns  : " + assTypes[i].Namespace);
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");

    }
}
```

The console does not print any result, *hasDataContractAttribute is never true*, how come?
It seems that **GetCustomAttributes** returns attributes that are applied to properties. but I'm looking for attributes that are applied to the interface level. Most online example show how to get custom attributes by reflection on attributes.

Comment: `assemblyArray[8]`. Yeah. What makes you so sure that the assembly you want to look into is exactly the assembly at index 8 in the array? Maybe its the 9th... or the 5th, or the last one in the array. Or maybe it's the 7th. Yes, thinking about it, it really must be the 7th... ;-P

Comment: yes that's the 8 assembly that the attribute is applied it is irrlevant, sorry i had to mention that

Comment: How do you know? What is the evidence for your claim?

Comment: `the 8th assembly` but you used `[8]` which means the 9th

Comment: yes the 9th, just ignore that part of the code, GetCustomAttributes is the focal point

Comment: Okay, let's ignore that. The answer/problem to your question, your focal point so to speak, is that none of the types in the assembly you query has the InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute applied. Hence _hasDataContractAttribute_ never being true. There is no magic trick involved, the explanation is as simple as that...

Comment: By the way, where is the InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute attribute implemented? Do you use separately compiled implementations for when you build the assembly and for when you wrote the code using reflection to search for the attribute? If you have two different code bases for the InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute type, then you technically have two distinct InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute types (even if they share the same name)

Comment: All projects where compiled before running the code, dlls for all projects have been created

Comment: No, that is not what i was asking about. When you built the DLL, where is/was the code for the InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute class? Was the InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute  class compiled as part of the assembly DLL, or is the InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute type provided by a third assembly DLL? If the DLL has its own InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute, and your program using reflection has its own InterfaceForPartialModelAttribute implementation, then thus two are entirely separate different unequal types. Do you understand that?

Comment: @elgonzo the interface and the custom attribute are both in the same project assembly, even if they where in different the result would have been the same. By calling GetCustomAttributes i can't see if the attribute is applied to the interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189704/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-luther).